# неопределенный индекс как заменить чтобы правильно работала

Tags: php

всем здарово есть функция для проверки авторизаций по моему код написан на php 5
я вот на 7 сижу куда передавать нужно данные точнее

```html
 function getAuth(){
  $id= $_SESSION['id'];
  $type= $_SESSION['type'];
  if ($id=='' AND $type=='')
   return false; 
  else
   return true;
```

Notice:  Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work_Log\main.php on line 42
Notice:  Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\Work_Log\main.php on line 43

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы php не выбрасывал нотайсы - выключи их ;) или сделай так(PHP4/5/7):

```
$id = isset($_SESSION['id'])? $_SESSION['id']: '';
$type= isset($_SESSION['type'])? $_SESSION['type']: '';
```

Или так(PHP7):

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'] ?? '';
$type= $_SESSION['type']) ?? '';
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло это что получается просто уведомления или какая то ошибка с версиями